# Controller crash when returning ef core objects with navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

My env is 
Asp.Net Core 2.1
EF Core 2.1

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerLocation> CustomerLocations { get; set; }


public class CustomerLocation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int customerId { get; set; }
    public string streetAddress { get; set; }
    public string zipCode { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

In my Api controller

```
    // GET: api/Customers
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        var custlist = _context.Customers
            .Include(c=>c.CustomerLocations)
            .ToList();

        return custlist;

    }
```

and I would like to receive this JSON

```
[
{
    id: 1,
    name: "My First Company",
    customerLocations: [
    {
        id: 1,
        customerId: 1,
        streetAddress: "13 Union Street",
        zipCode: "94111",
        city: "San Francisco",
        state: "CA",
        category: "Headquarter",
        customer: null
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        customerId: 1,
        streetAddress: "1098 Harrison St",
        zipCode: "94103",
        city: "San Francisco",
        state: "CA",
        category: "Warehouse",
        customer: null
    }]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Another Company",
    customerLocations: [ ]
}
]
```

but the answer i receive is

```
[
{
    id: 1,
    name: "My First Company",
    customerLocations: [
    {
        id: 1,
        customerId: 1,
        streetAddress: "13 Union Street",
        zipCode: "94111",
        city: "San Francisco",
        state: "CA",
        category: "Headquarter"
```

then it crashes trying to loop into the "customer" navigation property of "customerLocation".

The only way I found to get rid of this is to explicitly null all "customer" references in each CustomerLocation, but I can't believe this is the correct way to deal with this.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @ofiris I can't get no exception. If I debug controller execution all is ok until the return statement is executed. Then in the browser I only have a JSON structure truncated just before the "customer" property. If I use Postman & Fiddler I get this response "[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 530 bytes."

Comment: You might found solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002940/json-and-circular-reference-exception

Comment: @karan thank you for your reference, but it seems outdated (8 years ago); this has to be a EF core 2.1 problem, I did not have this problem with EF6.

Comment: While serializing your model , JSON.Net is finding a circular reference and breaks . You can either decorate "Customer" property in your CustomerLocation class with [JsonIgnore] attribute or use configuration described @ [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521722/how-to-stop-self-referencing-loop-in-net-core-web-api) to handle this. Also, read [this blog post](https://dotnetminds.com/handle-circular-reference-problem-asp-dot-net-mvc-core/) for issues associated with both the approaches.

Comment: Can you provide your startup code please?

Comment: First, "crashing" means the application crashes (=stops working) which isn't the case, since exceptions are handled gracefully. Second, never return EF Core entities this way, because of that (see @Kahbazi's answer below). Always create models which don't have two way navigation properties and map to them. Because if you ever change your EF Core model, you break your API and all clients that consume it, since its a breaking change

Comment: @Tseng Ok for the incorrect usage of the term "crash". Why do I have to avoid two way navigation properties? If I have Company with many workers, how can I get to the list of companies  starting from a list of workers if I do not have a "Company" nav property in "Worker"?

Comment: I said **two-way navigation properties** Company -> Workers -> Company. This can (and most likely will) cause circular dependencies. The other reason is just, that your public api won't be stable as you can't change your entities w/o breaking the API. When you have DTOs (call them ViewModels, BindingModels, etc.), then you can change or rename fields on the persistence (EF Core) Model w/o breaking the clients who access your api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of this error is Reference Loop while serializing `Customer`, and as you said when you set customer reference to `null`, you avoid the reference loop.

The other way that you can handle it is to set `ReferenceLoopHandling` for Json serializer in `startup.cs`

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(config =>
    {
        config.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```