# Reference Loop Handling Ignore not working on Asp.Net Core 3.0 Preview 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I have been beating my head against a wall with this one, trying to find out why it won't work. I haven't been able to find anything on why it won't work, so I am asking here.

I have a console application that is running on Asp.Net Core 3.0 Preview 3.

On this project I am getting a Json loop problem, which I know I can fix with setting the Reference Loop Handling in Startup to Ignore. However, I could only find information on setting it inside the .AddJsonOptions(), which doesn't appear to be in Asp.Net Core 3.0.

I went to the documentation for how to migrate from 2.1 to 3.0 and I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support)

Even after changing my code accordingly

```
services.AddMvc()
     .AddNewtonsoftJson(
          options => { options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; }
      );
```

I still get an error saying: "Self referencing loop detected for property '[insert class name]' with type '[model name]'."

Where else can I set Json to ignore the loop reference?

Or what can I do to make this work?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Have you tried doing the serialization explicitly, i.e serialize the object/data in a method or in your controller action. like so
`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, new JsonSerializerSettings().ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)`

I believe this will take precedence over what you have in your startup.cs class

Comment: looks similar: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8480

Comment: FWIW, this type of thing generally becomes a non-issue if you use proper DTOs, instead of things like entity classes directly. With a DTO class(es), you can remove the reference loop entirely from the equation.

Comment: Thanks all of you, UgoOkoro that works thank you. However, I am going to go for creating DTOs like ChrisPratt said that should make this a non-issue. I had briefly thought about doing something like DTOs, but I didn't know there was a name for it and everything. Thank you guys.

Comment: do you add app.useMvc() in configure method?

Comment: Please look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58517316/4656623) for the solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options=> options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support

Answer (score 4):

As explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55666826/where-did-imvcbuilder-addjsonoptions-go-in-net-core-3-0) as part of ASP.NET Core 3.0, the team moved away from including Newtonsoft.Json by default.

You probably need to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` and use (note, I'm using .AddNewtonsoftJson() chained with .AddControllers()) something similar:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(x =>
            {
                x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
```