# E.F Core and Automapper not getting all data when getting by id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper-7

I'm using EF Core and Auto Mapper in an ASP.NET CORE api and I am having a little bit of trouble understanding why I am not getting all my data when I get it by ID.

When I debug and look at the data it is all there in the variable but when it hits the automapper part it is like some data is ignored.

How can I get all the data with the corresponding Id.

this is my method for the GetAsset by Id.

```
[HttpGet("{key:int}", Name = "getAsset")]
        [EnableQuery]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AssetDto>> GetAsset(int key)
        {
            var asset = await _context.Assets.Include(c => c.Category)
                .Include(m => m.Manufacturer)
                .Include(c => c.Condition)
                .Include(l => l.Location)
                .Include(f => f.AssetFiles)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == key);
            
            if (asset == null) return NotFound();

            var assetDto = _mapper.Map<AssetDto>(asset);
            return assetDto;
        }
```

Here is my mapping with automapper

```
CreateMap<Asset, AssetDto>().ReverseMap();
```

here is my AssetDTO

```
public class AssetDto
    {   //  Get and sets the Id property
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the Name Property and sets it to required
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the CategoryId property
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the CategoryName property set it to NotMapped
        [NotMapped]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the ManufacturerId property
        public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the ManufacturerName property set it to NotMapped
        [NotMapped]
        public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
        //Gets and sets the Model property
        public string Model { get; set; }
        //Gets and sets the SerialNumber property
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the PurchasePlace property
        public string PurchasePlace { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the Quantity property
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the AcquiredDate property
        public DateTime AcquiredDate { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the PurchasePrice property/
        public float PurchasePrice { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the CurrentValue property
        public float CurrentValue { get; set; }
        //Gets and sets the ConditionId property
        public int ConditionId { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the ConditionName property set it to NotMapped/
        [NotMapped]
        public string ConditionName { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the LocationId property
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the LocationName property set it to NotMapped
        [NotMapped]
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the RetiredDate property
        public DateTime RetiredDate { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the Description property
        public string Description { get; set; }
        // Gets and sets the Files property set it to NotMapped
        [NotMapped]
        public ICollection<AssetFileDto> Files { get; set; } <-- updated
    }
```

and my Asset Model

```
public class Asset
    {   // Int property that gets/sets id
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // String property that gets/sets Name
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //Foreign Key
        //Int property that gets/sets category id
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        // Int property that gets/sets Manufacturer id
        public int? ManufacturerId { get; set; }
        // String property that gets/sets model
        public string Model { get; set; }
        // String property that gets/sets serial number
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        // String property that gets/sets purchase place
        public string PurchasePlace { get; set; }
        //Int property that gets/sets quantity
        public int? Quantity { get; set; }
        // Datetime property that gets/sets acquired date
        public DateTime AcquiredDate { get; set; }
        // Float property that gets/sets purchase price
        public float? PurchasePrice { get; set; } 
        //Float property that gets/sets current value
        public float? CurrentValue { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        // Int property that gets/sets condition id
        public int? ConditionId { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        // Int property that gets/sets location id
        public int? LocationId { get; set; }
        // Datetime property that gets/sets retired date
        public DateTime RetiredDate { get; set; }
        //String property that gets/sets description
        public string Description { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        // Collection of asset files
        public ICollection<AssetFile> AssetFiles { get; set; }
        // Navigation Property
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        // Navigation Property
        public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
        // Navigation Property
        public Condition Condition { get; set; }
        //Navigation Property
        public Location Location { get; set; }
    }
```

The data that I am missing is the CategoryName, ManufacturerName, ConditionName LocationName, And All the asset files that are connected to the asset

When I do a normal get request in postman I get all the data no problem. But when getting it by ID the above fields are missing and I don't know why

any guidance would be grateful

Update:

assetFile DTO

```
public class AssetFileDto
    {
        // Int property that gets/sets the id
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // Byte property that gets/sets the files
        public byte[] Files { get; set; }
        // String property that gets/sets the name
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // String property that gets/sets the mime type
        public string MimeType { get; set; }
    }
```

assetFile.cs

```
public class AssetFile
    {
        // Int property that gets/sets the id
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        // Byte property that gets/sets the File
        public byte[] File { get; set; }
        // String property that gets/sets Name
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // String property that gets/sets the mime type
        public string MimeType { get; set; }
        //Int property that gets/sets the asset id 
        public int AssetId { get; set; }
        // Asset navigation property
        public Asset Asset { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like all the properties annotated with [NotMapped] are missing in your response, could you try removing that Annotation and check?

Comment: Just tried without the annotations and still got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expand on your mapping profile. AutoMapper can't work everything out for you. It only maps the properties with the same names automatically.

For example, if you want `CategoryName`

```
CreateMap<Asset, AssetDto>()
  .ForMember(x => x.CategoryName, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Category.Name))
  .ReverseMap();
```

---

It's not directly related to this question, but I would recommend that you use [ProjectTo](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) so you only select the fields you need, instead of loading them into memory and then filtering.

---

I checked to see if it worked by added your entities to a local project.
Some of the stuff I changed was for part of the demo, so you can just notice the changes and then apply the relevant ones to your code.

**Controller / Service**

Inject `IMapper` and use `ProjectTo`

(you'll need `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`, if you don't have it already).

```
private readonly IMapper Mapper;

/* Inject into controller constructor */

public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsset(int key)
{
    var asset = await Db.Assets
            .Where(i => i.Id == key)
            .ProjectTo<AssetDto>(Mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (asset == null) return NotFound();

    return Json(asset);
}
```

**AssetFileDto**

If you want it to match with your `AssetFile`, `Files` should be called `File`.

```
 public byte[] File { get; set; }
```

**Mapping Profile**

You should then have a mapping profile that looks something like this

```
 CreateMap<Asset, AssetDto>()
     .ForMember(x => x.Files, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.AssetFiles));

 CreateMap<AssetFile, AssetFileDto>();
```

Comment: When I try to map the asset files like this ```.ForMember(f => f.Files, f = f.MapFrom(k => k.AssetFiles)).ReverseMap();```
 I get the following error in postman
 ```Self referencing loop detected with type 'home_inventory.Models.AssetFile'. Path 'files[0].asset.assetFiles'.```
 how would i get around this in the mapping of the files ?

Comment: You should have another DTO for `AssetFile` and then put that in your `AssetDTO` and create a mapping for it. e.g. `public ICollection<AssetFileDTO> Files { get; set; }` and `CreateMap<AssetFile, AssetFileDTO>();`

Comment: I implemented what you recommended but still getting the self referencing loop error in postman

Comment: You should be able to sort it by looking at the entity but it's difficult to say without seeing it. You can always just disable reference loop handling in the `Startup.cs` by following an answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58475098/3688864).

Comment: Tried disabling it and did not go through. Just weird why the mapping is not working how would you do the ForMember. did it look like i had it right  i tried it also on the mapping for the assetfiles => assetfilesdto and still did notwork. Will keep trying to find a solution.

Comment: Can you edit your question with what your `AssetFile` and `AssetFileDTO` looks like? Can you also explain what "did not go through" means?

Comment: Edited the original post and did not go though was the attempt at disabling the Json reference loop./

Comment: It seemed to work when I checked it. I've edited my answer with what I did. Hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help